# Как сохранить пароль подключения в Access

Tags: пароль, ms-access

Есть база в `Sql Server`. С помощью `Access` подключился к базе. Но постоянно требует пароль при открытии. Думал сперва открыть доступ к гостевой учетке, но безопасники быстро остановили меня). В общем никак не пойму как сохранить пароль в самой базе, а не вбивать постоянно.

Comment: Связанные таблицы используете?

Comment: да, используется

Comment: тогда можно попробовать покдключаться через ODBC. Если не ошибаюсь, там можно сохранить пароль.